# How to add into web service iteration element in @GET?

Tags: java, web-services, get, iteration

I have to return in my web service another data on another GET request.

This is the following code:

```
int i=0;
    @GET
    public List<Sensor> getSensors(){
        if (i <= 3){
            return sensorService.getAllSensorsFromMoment(i);
            i++
        }
        return sensorService.getAllSensors();
    }
```

When I added i++ in that code but I have an error (unreachable code). Any ideas how to fix this code that it will be correctly working?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is simple. I solved the problem.

```
if(this.i<=3){
        i++;
        return sensorService.getAllSensorsFromMoment(i);
    }
```

I added i++ after return.